# Date range filter with Yajra Datatables as Service

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using Yajra Datatables as Service for my Laravel 7.x project. I want to set a date range filter (from date, to date) from my View. How can i do that?

Controller:

```
public function orderview(OrderDataTable $dataTable ){
    $from_date = date('2020-01-01 00:00:00');
    $to_date = Carbon::now();
    return $dataTable
        ->with([
            'from' => $from_date,
            'to' => $to_date,
            ])
        ->render('admin.search.order');
    // return $dataTable->render('admin.search.order');
}
```

Datatables:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

// use App\App\OrderDataTable;
// use OrderDataTable;
use App\DataTables\OrderDataTable;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;
use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class OrderDataTable extends DataTable
{

    public function dataTable($query){
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query);
    }


    public function query(OrderDataTable $model){
        // $from = date('2020-11-10 00:00:00');
        // $to = date('2020-11-11 23:59:59');
        // $data = Order::where('created_at', '2020-11-11 22:03:13');
        // $data = Order::select();
        $data = Order::query()
            // ->whereBetween('created_at', ['2020-11-10 00:00:00', '2020-11-11 23:59:59'])
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->from, $this->to])
            ->select([
                'orders.id',
                'orders.ecomordid',
                'orders.status_id',
                'orders.awb',
                'orders.created_at'
            ]);
        return $this->applyScopes($data);
    }


    public function html(){
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('orderdatatable-table')
                    // ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->columns([
                        'id' => [ 'title' => 'SHIPPING CODE' ],
                        'ecomordid' => [ 'title' => 'ECOM ORDER' ],
                        'status_id' => [ 'title' => 'STATUS' ],
                        'awb' => [ 'title' => 'AWB' ],
                        'created_at' => [ 'title' => 'DATE' ],
                    ])
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->dom('Bfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(0)
                    ->parameters([
                        'dom'          => 'Bfrtip',
                        'buttons'      => ['excel', 'print', 'reset', 'reload'],
                        'initComplete' => "function () {
                            this.api().columns([0,3]).every(function () {
                                var column = this;
                                var input = document.createElement(\"input\");
                                $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                                .on('change', function () {
                                    column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
                                });
                            });
                        }",
                    ]);
    }


    protected function getColumns(){
        return [
            Column::make('id'),
            Column::make('ecomordid'),
            Column::make('status_id'),
            Column::make('awb'),
            Column::make('created_at'),
        ];
    }


    protected function filename(){
        return 'Order_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-orange"><h3>{{ __('Update By AWB') }}</h3></div>
                <div class="card-body">

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">Total Records - <b><span id="total_records"></span></b></div>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                 <div class="input-group input-daterange">
                                     <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date"  class="form-control" />
                                     &nbsp;<div class="input-group-addon">To</div>&nbsp;
                                     <input type="text"  name="to_date" id="to_date"  class="form-control" />
                                 </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                 <button type="button" name="filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Filter</button>
                                 <button type="button" name="refresh" id="refresh" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Refresh</button>
                                </div>
                               </div>

                        </div>


                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                {!! $dataTable->table([], true) !!}
                                {!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Currently i am displaying date from:

```
$from_date = date('2020-01-01 00:00:00');
$to_date = Carbon::now();
```

But i want to pass the date from View (from_date & to_date field) to controller and display the result by matched date. How can i do this? Please help.

[My Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHxfH.png)

**I am using:**

Laravel: 7.28.4
laravel-datatables-buttons: 4.0
laravel-datatables-html: 4.0
laravel-datatables-oracle: 9.14

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have done that a few weeks ago for a transaction view. Have a look at my code and see if that can help you.

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Gate;
use App\Models\Merchant;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Datatables;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TransactionController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        ///[...]
        if ($request->ajax()) {

            $query = Transaction::with(['customer', 'merchant', 'batch'])->select(sprintf('%s.*', (new Transaction)->table))
                    ->where('merchant_id', '=', $merch);
            // Date Range Picker
            if (isset($request->columns[2]['search']['value'])){
            $dates = explode (' - ', $request->columns[2]['search']['value']);
                $query = $query->where("transaction_date",">=",$dates[0])
                ->where("transaction_date","<=",$dates[1]);
            }

            $table = Datatables::of($query);

            $table->addColumn('placeholder', '&nbsp;');
            $table->addColumn('actions', '&nbsp;');

            $table->editColumn('actions', function ($row) {
                GLOBAL $request;

                $viewGate      = 'transaction_show';
                $editGate      = 'transaction_edit';
                $deleteGate    = 'transaction_delete';
                $crudRoutePart = 'transactions';

                return view('partials.datatablesActions', compact(
                    'viewGate',
                    'editGate',
                    'deleteGate',
                    'crudRoutePart',
                    'row',
                    'merch'
                ));
            });

            $table->rawColumns(['actions', 'placeholder', 'merchant']);

            return $table->make(true);
        }

        return view('admin.transactions.index', compact('merch'));
    }
    ///[...]
}
```

My View

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.title_singular') }} {{ trans('global.list') }}
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">

        <table style="font-size: 12px; cursor: pointer;" class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover ajaxTable datatable datatable-Transaction">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10">

                    </th>
                    <th style="width:150px">
                        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.merchant') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.transaction_date') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.type') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.amount') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.ref') }}
                    </th>
                    <th width="45">
                        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.auth') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.card') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.description') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        &nbsp;
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if($merch=="all" and (auth()->user()->isAdmin()||auth()->user()->isSuperAdmin()||auth()->user()->isIso()||auth()->user()->isAgent()))
                        <select style="height: 25px; width: 200px;" class="search">
                            <option value>{{ trans('global.all') }}</option>
                            @foreach($merchants as $key => $item)
                                <option value="{{ $item->name }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="width:150px" id="reportrange" class="search" type="text">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select style="height: 25px;" class="search">
                            <option value="elavon">Elavon</option>
                            <option value="dd">Discount</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="height: 25px; width:75px;" id="datetest" class="search" type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('global.search') }}">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="height: 25px; width:75px;" id="datetest" class="search" type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('global.search') }}">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="height: 25px; width:75px;" id="datetest" class="search" type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('global.search') }}">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="height: 25px; width:75px;" id="datetest" class="search" type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('global.search') }}">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
@parent
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

let dtButtons = $.extend(true, [], $.fn.dataTable.defaults.buttons)

let dtOverrideGlobals = {
    buttons: dtButtons,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    retrieve: true,
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, 1000], [10, 25, 50, 100, 1000]],
    aaSorting: [],
    ajax: "{{ route('admin.transactions.index', array('merch'=>$merch)) }}",
    columns: [
        { data: 'placeholder', name: 'placeholder' },
        { data: 'merchant_name', name: 'merchant.name' },
        { data: 'transaction_date', name: 'transaction_date' },
        { data: 'transaction_type', name: 'transaction_type' },
        { data: 'amount', name: 'amount' },
        { data: 'trn_ref_num', name: 'trn_ref_num' },
        { data: 'authorization_code', name: 'authorization_code' },
        { data: 'card_no', name: 'card_no' },
        { data: 'charge_type_description', name: 'charge_type_description' },
        { data: 'actions', name: '{{ trans('global.actions') }}' }
    ],
    orderCellsTop: true,
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    pageLength: 50,
};
let table = $('.datatable-Transaction').DataTable(dtOverrideGlobals);
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab click', function(e){
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust();
});

$('.datatable thead').on('keyup change', '.search', function () {
    let strict = $(this).attr('strict') || false
    let value = strict && this.value ? "^" + this.value + "$" : this.value
    table
        .column($(this).parent().index())
        .search(value, strict)
        .draw()
});

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start + ' - ' + end);
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        locale: {
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        },
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
            // 'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);


});
</script>
@endsection
```

Basacly in the view I have an input with #reportrange that is then initialized by jquery $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({[...]});

The daterange library is this one: https://github.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker

When a search is initialized, data table refreshes and sends a new ajax request to the controller where if ($request->ajax()) returns true. I then explode the date value and create the right SQL. You will need to change the $request->columns[2]['search']['value'] part and matches the right column number. You can retrieve that from the developer tool when you look at the request from chrome.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for sharing the code. Actually my problem is I am using Yajra Datatables as Service. i can pass the parameter from the View to Controller with AJAX and then again pass the parameter to DataTable (service) but i dont know to display the return data to blade. 

For conventional datatable i can use jquery to populate the table or append the data to the field directly. But for this datatables as service i am totally lost :(

Comment: It's the same thing. You just need a script in your view that comunicates with the controller https://datatables.yajrabox.com/